# Detect a line return character in a MS Word text string using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to parse structured paragraphs in a set of Word files before writing them to an Excel workbook to create a flat-file data table for analysis.

Each Word file consists of a set of paragraphs, each of which comprise a set of "fields" separated by line returns.

Example:

```
Event Type: a short description of the event...
Location: Text description of the location where the event occurred
Time: a date-time text for when the event occurred
```

[image: Example of Word file text]

I use one function to locate where each field name begins within the paragraph and to extract that name. Another function returns the text associated with each of the fields. I identify the first character location in the text data, then iterate through the remaining text until I reach a line return which marks the end of the string I wish to return. The function code is:

```vb
Function Return_Text(strText as String, strFind as String) as String
' strText contains the text of the entire paragraph
' strFind is the text string for the desired field name

Dim intStart as Integer, ctr as Integer

If InStr(strText, strFind) Then
    intStart = InStr(strText, strFind)
    For ctr = intStart + Len(strFind) To Len(strText)
        If Mid(strText, ctr, 1) = vbLf Then     ' This is the comparison that is causing problems
            Return_Text = Mid(strText, intStart + Len(strFind), ctr)
            Exit For
        End If
        If Len(Return_Text) > 0 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ctr
End If
```

I've been unable to come up with a suitable comparison character for a line return in Word, I tried VBA constants (vbCr, vbLf, vbCrLf), ASCI codes (Chr(10), Chr(13)), and "\n".

Comment: Your demo text needto be replaced with a screeen shot of what is visible in word when all text markers are being shown.  That way we can see better how your text is structured.  You also need to use F8 to step through your code line by line.  Make sure the locals windows is open.  What do you see for the value of strText.  Finally, you might want to read up on the VBA function Split.

Comment: To split up paragraphs, why not use `ThisDocument.Paragraphs`? If you want to combine some of them in output, its much easier to start with the `Paragraphs` collection rather than build your own custom text parser.

Comment: Also, for each line, you could split the line into two parts, before and after `:`. Using Split, with a limit of 2 parts, you can quickly get the category and text as an Array of Strings, `Split(ThisDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text, ":", 2)`

Comment: I have already stepped through the execution of the script using F8 and when I get to the location where the non-printing line return character is, the debugger value shows a placeholder (looks like "[]") which lets me know that it sees the line return character, but I can't tell what symbol or value I can compare it to.
In the main program, I have a loop set up to step through each paragraph using [For Each Paragraph in ActiveDocument.Paragraphs]

Comment: can you give me the sample file of that pic, I'll try. Every symbol after the "23" must be more than just a return. The code you gave is so small that it is hard to fully understand what the logic of your operation is.

Comment: Have you tried using Find to replace the line break with another character, e.g. tab, paragraph mark?

Comment: If strText really contains the entire paragraph text, then you can show the character at the end using ascw(right(strText,1)) and the character before that (if there is more than one using  ascw(right(strText,2)). The "hard return" (e.g. the one after GA, TX and OK in your example) *should be* 11 = asc(vbVerticalTab) and the paragraph mark (after "23") *should be* 13 = asc(vbCr). If you put theses texts in a tavle cell you may also get an end-of-cell character at the end of the string, and that's a 7.

Answer (score 0):

If the line separator was inserted with Shift-Enter (line-break) Search for ASC=11

Comment: Thanks! Chr(11) worked perfectly for identifying the linefeed (Shift-Enter) character in my Word files.